# Why does my code output enumaration values instead of a string?

Tags: ruby

I'm writing  dictionary based attack program in ruby for a CTF, but my output prints an enumeration value instead of a string. I've tried explicingly converting the variable that ouputs to a string, but that did not change anything.

```
require 'net/http'

def checkUsage()
  if ARGV.length != 1
    return false
  end
  return true
end


def generateUsername()

  wordArray = Array.new
  wordlist = File.open("words.txt", "r")

  for word in wordlist
    wordArray.push(word)
  end

 return wordArray.repeated_permutation(7).to_s

end

def generatePassword()

  wordArray = Array.new
  wordlist = File.open("words.txt", "r")

  for word in wordlist
    wordArray.push(word)
  end

  return wordArray.repeated_permutation(7).to_s

end

def requestAuthentication()

  if(!checkUsage())
    puts("Usage: frsDic <wordlist>")
    return false
  end

  uri = URI("http://challenges.laptophackingcoffee.org:3199/secret.php")
  req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)

  loop do

    username = generateUsername()
    password = generatePassword()

    if req.basic_auth username, password
      puts"Username found: " + username
      puts"Password found: " + password
      break
    else
      puts"Username failed: " + username
      puts"Password failed: " + password
    end
  end
end


requestAuthentication()
```

Output:

```
#<Enumerator:0x000055a491c74ad0>
#<Enumerator:0x000055a491c74828>
#<Enumerator:0x000055a491c74ad0>
#<Enumerator:0x000055a491c74828>
```

I was expecting to print out the string of the usernames/passwords found by the bruteforce, but it only printed enumeration values.

Comment: I do not get the listed output when I run the script. I get `Usage: frsDic <wordlist>`

Comment: You need to pas a wordlist as an argument :/

Comment: Note   `if ARGV.length != 1; return false; end; return true` in `check_usage` can be simplified to `if ARGV.length != 1; false; end; true`, which can be simplified to `ARGV.length == 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [`repeated_permutation`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Array.html#method-i-repeated_permutation) returns an Enumerator if you don't provide a block. If you're looking to loop through all of the permutations, you can either pass a block directly to it:

```
wordArray.repeated_permutation(7) { |permutation| puts permutation }
```

Or you can pass the enumerator somewhere and call `.each` on it.

```
word_enumerator = wordArray.repeated_permutation(7)
word_enumerator.each { |permutation| puts permutation }
```